# Iterating through csv

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to parse a csv:

```
col1,col2,col3
a,b,1
d,e,2
```

when I run the following code

```
var fs = require("fs");
var d3 = require("d3");

fs.readFile("test.csv", "utf8", function(error, data) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(d3.csvParse(data));
        data.map((item, i) => console.log(`Hello ${item.col1} this ${item.col2} there are ${item.col3} blabla`));
});
```

I get TypeError: data.map is not a function

While the following is running fine.

```
var data = [{ "col1":"a","col2":"b","col3":1},
            { "col1":"d","col2":"e","col3":2}]

data.map((item, i) => console.log(`Hello ${item.col1} this ${item.col2} there are ${item.col3} blabla`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.csvParse` returns an array, but you convert it to a string here:

`var data = JSON.stringify(d3.csvParse(data));`

Strings don't have `.map`, of course. You probably want to iterate over the array:

```
const newData = d3.csvParse(data);
newData.forEach((item, i) => console.log(`Hello ${item.col1} this ${item.col2} there are ${item.col3} blabla`));
```

(don't use `.map` because you aren't transforming it into a new array, at least not in the code you've posted)

Comment: I got confused because when I run console.log(data) on the D3 code it returns [{"col1":"a","col2":"b","col3":"1"},{"col1":"d","col2":"e","col3":"2"}] which to me is the same as my var data.